# Assetic doesn't work Symfony 3

Tags: php, css, symfony, assetic

I have a application with two different base twig files. One is for the main application and the other is for the docs for the application.

In both base files i use different css files. In one base it works and in a other one it does not work.

This is the working base file

```
     {% stylesheets output='css/compiled/main.min.css'
        '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/feedback.css'
        '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/general.css'
        '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/portal.css'
        '@UserBundle/Resources/public/css/*.css'
     %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

and this is the base file that does not work

```
    {% stylesheets output='css/compiled/knowledge.min.css'
        '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/knowledgeCenter.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

I have in mijn assetic.yml (which is included in my config.yml)

```
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
read_from:      "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
bundles:        [ ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    scssphp:
        formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
    uglifyjs2:
        bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifyjs
    uglifycss:
        bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifycss
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

The folder @CoreBundle/Resources/public/css looks the following

[image]

Note: the knowledgeCenter.css is compiled by phpstorm from scss
Note: the .css file is not in the .scss file it is something that phpstorm shows

My console looks like this when i update the assets

[image]

As you can see it does not include the css i made in the public/css folder

I have tried the following

- Cleaned all the cache and installed assets again with php bin/console

  (i tried these commands

  bin/console cache:clear

  bin/console cache:clear --env=prod

  bin/console assets:install web

  bin/console assetic:dump

  bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod

  )
- Made a .css file instead of a .css file generated by phpstrom from scss
- changed the output from the not working base stylesheet to 'css/compiled/main.min.css'

All the following things did not work

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I'm probably being silly, but is it trying to find '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/knowledgeCenter.css' And yet that structure image you gave it'd actually be '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/knowledgeCenter.scss/knowledgeCenter.css'

Comment: it is not the mistake when i look to the files in finder it shows all the files normal i think it is something from phpstrom that the file is in the .scss file

Comment: As you probably know, assetic is no longer included by default in S3.  The thinking is to use many of the other js/css specific tools available.  So this might be a good time to consider switching to something like gulp?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/php.html) here says like this. Maybe u forgot the filter options.

```
{% stylesheets filter="scssphp" output="css/app.css"
    "assets/scss/bootstrap.scss"
    "assets/scss/font-awesome.scss"
    "assets/css/*.css"
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: i also tried it but still did not work for me the other one is also working without the filter function